# How to get city from facebook in MVC 4?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am making a website where I want to get details from Facebook login. I am currently getting details like Facebook id, first name, last name, gender, locale, link and profile picture. I want to get city also. After getting the city I want to check the city in database and according to which city the user is from I want to create border for that city in Google map. I am new to it and don't know how to do it. My coding is:

**FacebookUserModel.cs**

```
public partial class FacebookUserModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string locale { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string picture { get; set; }
    public int cityId { get; set; }
}
```

**City.cs**

```
public partial class City
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string iso { get; set; }
    public string local_name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> in_location { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> geo_lat { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> geo_lng { get; set; }
    public string db_id { get; set; }
}
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private DetailsFBEntities4 db = new DetailsFBEntities4();

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult FacebookLogin(FacebookLoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        Session["uid"] = model.uid;
        Session["accessToken"] = model.accessToken;
        Session["ip"] = Request.UserHostAddress;
        var client = new FacebookClient(Session["accessToken"].ToString());
        dynamic fbresult = client.Get("me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,gender,locale,link,picture,location");
        City city = new City();
        city.local_name = fbresult.location;
        FacebookUserModel facebookUser = new FacebookUserModel
        {
            first_name = fbresult.first_name,
            gender = fbresult.gender,
            id = fbresult.id,
            last_name = fbresult.last_name,
            locale = fbresult.locale,
            link = fbresult.link,
            picture = fbresult.picture.data.url,
            //cityId = fbresult.location,
        };
        //facebookUser.cityId = 85656;

        bool fb_id = db.FacebookUserModels.Any(fb => fb.id.Equals(facebookUser.id));
        if (fb_id)
        {
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
        else
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.FacebookUserModels.Add(facebookUser);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        //RedirectToAction("UserDetails");
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>

<!-- This css is to ensure that the google map contols (zoom bar etc) show and size correctly. -->
<style>
/*#map_canvas img{max-width:none}*/
    html, body, #map-canvas 
    {
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
</style>

<!-- This css is to give a nice big popup "info window" when a marker is clicked on the map -->
<style>
    .infoDiv {
    height: 200px;    
    width: 300px; 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    background-color: white; 
    }
</style>

<!-- This is the div that will contain the Google Map -->
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 600px;"></div>

<!-- Enclose the Javascript in a "section" so that it is rendered in the correct order after scripts have been loaded etc -->
@section scripts 
    {
    <section class="scripts">

<script type="text/javascript">

    <!-- This code tells the browser to execute the "Initialize" method only when the complete document model has been loaded. -->
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        Initialize();
    });

    // Where all the fun happens 
    function Initialize()
    {

        // These are options that set initial zoom level, where the map is centered globally to start, and the type of map to show
        var mapOptions =
            {
                zoom: 14,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.6928, -17.4467/*(geo_lat, geo_lng)*/),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.NORMAL,
                mapTypeControlOptions:
                {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                    mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, "map_style"]
                }
            };

        // This makes the div with id "map_canvas" a google map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

            // This shows adding a simple pin "marker" - this happens to be the Tate Gallery in Dakar!
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(14.6928, -17.4467);

            //generate polyline

        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    </section>
}
```

**Facebook.js**

```
function InitialiseFacebook(appId) {

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: appId,
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
            var credentials = { uid: response.authResponse.userID, accessToken: response.authResponse.accessToken };
            SubmitLogin(credentials);
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                alert("user is logged into fb");
            }
            else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') { alert("user is not authorised"); }
            else { alert("user is not conntected to facebook"); }

        });

        function SubmitLogin(credentials) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/account/facebooklogin",
                type: "POST",
                data: credentials,
                error: function () {
                    alert("error logging in to your facebook account.");
                },
                success: function () {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        }

    };

    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement('script');
        js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

}
```

Please help.